# How to start a private session of Firefox?

Tags: lubuntu, firefox

I'm new to Lubuntu. In Windows 7, I could right click the pinned Firefox icon and an option saying "Start Firefox in private mode" would be shown. Is there something similar for Lubuntu?

What I'm doing is running `$ firefox -private` in the terminal. But I'd prefer to have a shortcut or another way that doesn't need to keep the terminal opened, waiting for me to stop using Firefox.

**How can I have a button/shortcut where I'll simply click and open a private session of Firefox without opening a normal session of Firefox first?**

(I do *not* want to make the private mode the default behaviour. That is, I want Firefox to open by default in normal mode, but sometimes I want be able to start Firefox only in private mode)

---

Reason for Why I want this: I have many opened tabs in Firefox and when I close Firefox, they are saved and open again automatically when I start Firefox in *normal* mode. But sometimes I'm in a hurry and just want to search one thing, that's when I don't want Firefox to open all these tabs (my computer is old), and starting it in private mode allows me to only search for the thing I want and then close Firefox without losing the stored tabs. I don't want to save them all to bookmarks, because they change a lot and therefore I'd need to store and delete them all the time. Allowing Firefox to save them automatically is less of a hassle, and opening only in private mode avoids this problem.

Comment: @dsstorefile That makes for an answer if you ask me – maybe with links to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiple_profiles and https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles.

Comment: Thank you for all the infos! Creating different profiles would be kind of cumbersome, if I (un)install an addon in one I'd have to keep track of it in the other etc. It's easier to have just one profile. @dsstorefile Perfect! I didn't know I could exit after calling Firefox! I thought I needed to wait for it to be closed first. This a great answer

Comment: In those cases in terminal you can: Press Ctrl+z to suspend the current foreground job and then execute `bg` to make that command to execute in background.

Comment: Open firefox and then press `ctrl + shift + p`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop \
~/.local/share/applications/firefox-incognito.desktop
```

add `--private-window` to `Exec=`

add Incognito to `Name=`

you should now have a new launcher icon

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'Menu', choose 'Internet' & right click on Firefox, choose 'Properties' and edit the'Desktop entry' as: firefox %u --private-window. Firefox will now open a private window by default..